# How to show that the weak topology generated by family of functions is weaker than $\tau$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

[image]

In our lecture notes, the proof is given as above. Even though I understand some of the steps of the proof I really don't see how the final part finishes the proof and shows that the topology generated is weaker. Could someone please explain to me how this proof proves the above theorem?

Comment: What textbook are you using?

Comment: @user3879021 Not a published one I presume (by the mistakes in it), probably some teacher’s lecture notes. Written from an analyst’s view point not by a general topologies, that is clear.

Comment: E.g. the author writes $(\varepsilon_i, \varepsilon_i)$ even when the $\Bbb F$ can be $\Bbb C$… “this is implies that” instead of “this implies that” OAT. It’s a very sloppy definition of weak topology IMO.

Comment: So the theorem deals with arbitrary $X_\alpha$ and the proof restricts to $X_\alpha = \mathbb F = \mathbb R, \mathbb C$? That is strange, but even worse: It is wrong even in this special case. For $\mathbb F = \mathbb C$ it does not suffice  to consider preimages of  open intervals in $\mathbb R$, and  for $\mathbb F = \mathbb R$ it does not suffice to consider special intervals $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

All the elements of $\mathcal B$ are in $\tau$ by continuity of the $f_\alpha$ (as defined on $(X,\tau)$) and the fact that finite intersections of open sets are open.

As all open sets of the weak topology are unions of base elements and topologies are closed under unions all weak open sets are open in $\tau$ as well. Hence the theorem.

BTW the *correct* definition of the weak topology is to take as base all sets $\bigcap_{\alpha \in F} f_\alpha^{-1}[O_\alpha]$ where $F \in \mathcal G$ and all $O_\alpha$ are open subsets of $X_\alpha$ and where we can, if we wish, restrict them to a specific fixed base of $X_\alpha$ if we so wish. The definition as given is not correct as noted in the comments...

Comment: Perhaps you should say something about the inadequate definition of $\mathcal B$ in the question.

Comment: @PaulFrost I did (a bit) in my comment above. Nice addition by you btw. Too bad people don’t use a good text instead of semi correct lecture notes.